# Making a drawpad in processing Java, struggling for a user to create a square

Tags: java, processing

I am currently using Processing java and I am making a drawpad. I have done all the colours and drawing however now i want to let the user be able to create a square and drag the mouse for it to be a certain size. Like in the paint app on any computer.

So far ive tried a few ways, think they just need to be tweeked a bit and i can't get it to work! Ill post two of the ways i think that are the closest! If someone could give me a tip or help that would be appreciated!!  Thanks :)

```
 public void setup()
{
    size(1900,1000);
    smooth();
    background(255);

}

int posX, posY, pos2X, pos2Y;

void draw() 
{
}

void mousePressed()
{

  posX = mouseX;
  posY = mouseY;


}
 void mouseReleased()
 {
  pos2X = mouseX;
  pos2Y =mouseY;

  rect(posX,posY,  pos2X , pos2Y );
}
```

or

```
     public void setup()
    {
    size(1900,1000);
    smooth();
    background(255);


}

int posX, posY, pos2X, pos2Y;

void draw() {
}

  void mousePressed()
  {
if(mousePressed == true)
{
  posX = mouseX;
  posY = mouseY;
}
if(mousePressed == false)
{
  pos2X = mouseX;
  pos2Y =mouseY;
}

 rect(posX,posY,  pos2X , pos2Y );
 }
```

Comment: You will hardly be able to do that wthout wrapping this up into objects. Comment if you need help in that. Should be not too hard.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I tried it out and came up with the following: First you build a simple class which represents your square.

```
class Square
{
    float x, y, x2, y2;
    color col;
    public Square(float initPosX, float initPosY, color col) {
        this.x = initPosX;
        this.y = initPosY;
        this.col = col;
    }

    public void updateSize(float endx, float endy) {
        x2 = endx;
        y2 = endy;
    }

    public Square copy() {
        Square s = new Square(x,y,col);
        s.updateSize(x2,y2);
        return s;
    }

    public void display() {
      pushMatrix();
      translate(x,y);
      fill(col);
      rect(0,0,x2-x,y2-y);
      popMatrix();    
    }
}
```

It has four points and a color. At creation you will later pass your mouse position to it (x and y) and a color.

You want the square to be flexible resized as long as you keep the mouse down. This is why you have the method updateSize in the Square class where you pass the current mouse position.

Once you release the mouse, the square should not be able to be resized anymore. But it should still be drawn, so you need a collection to store your squares.

Therefore you introduce two variables - a current square (the one you resize until mouseReleased) and a collection to store the result:

```
Square currentSqare;
ArrayList<Square> squares;
```

Now you need to setup your sketch:

```
void setup() {  // this is run once.   

    // set the background color
    background(255);

    // canvas size (Integers only, please.)
    size(600, 600); 

    // smooth edges
    smooth();

    // limit the number of frames per second
    frameRate(30);

    // initialize collection 

    squares = new ArrayList<Square>();
}
```

Once you have these, you need the mechanism to add a new square on mousePressed and store it in the collection, once mouse has been released:

```
void mousePressed() {
    currentSqare = new Square(mouseX, mouseY,color(random(0,200),150,random(0,200)));
}

void mouseReleased() {
    squares.add(currentSqare.copy());
    currentSqare = null;
}
```

Note, that we store a copy of the square and not the reference itself, via copy (which is part of our Square class).

Finally we need to draw all squares:

```
void draw() {  // this is run repeatedly.  
    background(255);

    //draw all stored squares first
    for(Square sq : squares)
      sq.display();

    //if we pressed the mouse
    //and added a new square
    if (currentSqare != null) {
        currentSqare.updateSize(mouseX, mouseY);
        currentSqare.display();
    }
}
```

What you can do from here is to add classes for other primitives like circles, triangles or even extend Square for "Special" Squares. Hope that solved your problem well.